# pypi deployment error: invalid option "--password="

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to setup the deployment to pypi but I get an error after the test is build.
My travis-ci file is here:

https://github.com/EnlightNS/enlightns-cli/blob/master/.travis.yml

I used the setup pypi command line which generated the section in my `.travis.yml` file.

`travis setup pypi`

The build failure is here:

https://travis-ci.org/EnlightNS/enlightns-cli/jobs/78112477

The error is this one here:

```
Fetching: dpl-1.7.21.gem (100%)
Successfully installed dpl-1.7.21
1 gem installed
invalid option "--password="
failed to deploy
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [issue 327](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/issues/327) (opened by the OP), that was because the password had special characters in it.

And [the docs.travis-ci on encryption-key](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#Note-on-escaping-certain-symbols) does mention the  need to escape special characters such as braces, parentheses, backslashes, and pipe symbols.

> For example, when you want to assign the string 6&a(5!1Ab\ to FOO, you need to execute:

```
travis encrypt "FOO=6\\&a\\(5\\!1Ab\\\\"
```

> travis encrypts the string `FOO=6\&a\(5\!1Ab\\`, which then bash uses to evaluate in the build environment.
>
> Equivalently, you can do:

```
travis encrypt 'FOO=6\&a\(5\!1AB\\'
```